# A symmetric matrix producing a smaller symmetric matrix upon Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Given a real $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ and $a_{11}$ is non-zero, if you use Gaussian Elimination to reduce it to $$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_1^T \\ 0 & A_2 \end{pmatrix} , $$ $A_2$ will be an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ symmetric matrix.

How do you prove this?

I played around with $LA = U \to(LA)^T = U^T \rightarrow A^TL^T = U^T \to AL^T = U^T $ and so on, but I can't draw any conclusions about $A_2$.

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that $A_2$ will be symmetric. Do you have a reason to believe that this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

After the first step of the LU factorization, we have
$$
L_1^{-1}A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-l_{21} & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}^T \\ a_{12} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}^T \\
0 & -l_{21}a_{12}^T+A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $l_{21}:=a_{12}/a_{11}$, which is clearly symmetric because
both $A_{22}$ and $l_{21}a_{12}^T=a_{12}a_{12}^T/a_{11}$ are symmetric.